# Cant find out if this is the right code?

Tags: python

Hello I have to program the question bellow ( my code is under that) However once your read the question you will understand that I need the code to also add all the previous numbers. If someone could see my code and tell me if it is already doing that and if not how I could go about it I tried something which didn't work as the answer kept coming as 0.

THE QUESTION:

> As you know the inventor of the game chess was quite a
>   clever fellow. As the story goes  the inventor presented the game to
>   the king and the king was quite pleased. The king  asked what the
>   inventor wanted as payment. He asked for a grain of cereal for the
>   first square and to have each of the next 63 squares double the
>   previous square. As the story  goes the king agrees, but was not too
>   pleased by the final payment. Create a program that  computes how much
>   grain the king had to pay. Express your answer in pounds; assume 
>   there are 7000 grains to a pound.

MY CODE:

```
count = 0 
number1 = 1 
num = 2

while count < 63:
    num = num * 2
    count += 1

print "He payed ", num, " Pounds."
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tag homework questions with [tag:homework], which provides us with an indicator that we should do a better job explaining answers and less time just fixing the code. :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, you don't need to sum the amounts at all, since the sum of squares 1..n is 2^n-1 grains. In fact, here's a complete solution: `print (pow(2,64)-1)/7000`. Kinda lame programming homework if you ask me.

Comment: If you tried something that didn't work you should have shown that as well. Perhaps it was almost right and ew would notice that?

Comment: @Juhana sum of *powers of two from 0 to n-1* is 2^(n)-1 :)

Comment: @Ord Exactly! And square n has 2^(n-1) grains on it :)

Comment: @Ord Ok, I just realized what you were saying: I meant "square" as a square on the chess board (as in the story), not in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @Juhana Ohhh ... got it :)  My bad - that's what I get for nitpicking I guess.

Comment: What did your program output? Why do you have the `number1` variable in your code? Why is `num` initialized to 2? What would your code look like if there were 1 square on the board, or 2? Are you computing grains or pounds in your code? Why do engineers always answer questions with questions?

Answer (score 2):

```
count=0
number1=1
num=2

while count<63:
   num=num*2
   count+=1

print"He payed ",num," Pounds."
```

A few comments: you're not using `number1` in your code -- it's best to remove unused variables, as their presence can easily distract you from the real flow of the code. Second, because you're starting with `num=2`, you're actually going to come up with the number of grains of cereal on the 65th square of a bigger-than-usual board.

There's a neat algebraic trick available to you though:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^n == 2^(n+1) - 1
```

So if you instead compute:

```
2 ^ 64 - 1
```

you'll get the number of grains of cereal asked for. (Note that I've given this answer in usual mathematical notation -- *not* Python notation. `2 ^ 64` does something different in Python. Use `**` instead for [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).)

Then divide that number by 7,000 to get the pounds as the question *ultimately* wanted.

Of course, if the whole point of the exercise is to teach looping, then the algebraic equality is going against the purpose of the exercise -- but these sorts of equalities are an important part of programming.

Comment: Should be 2 ^ 64 - 1 ... the first square is 2^0, so the 64th square is 2^63.

Comment: @Ord, _thanks_. Sheesh. After I even mentioned the over-calculation in the program fragment ...

Answer (score 0):

See sarnold's answer for the "shortcut" to the answer. However, if you want to do this through looping, then make the following changes to your code:

1. num should start as 1, since only one grain was paid for the first square
2. while loop should read while count<64 ... that way the loop runs exactly 64 times, once for each square on the board
3. Make a new variable, called total perhaps. Initialize it to zero. After each `num=num*2` line, you should go `total += num` - num only gives you the amount the king paid for one square, so you should use total to accumulate the results for all squares.
4. At the end, divide your anser (`total`) by 7000, since there are 7000 grains to a pound.

Also, some ways to clean up the code:

1. Try using a `for` loop instead of a while. Then you don't need to explicitly increment count. You can use: `for count in range(0,64):`, and then delete your explicit declaration of count (`count=0`) and `count+=1`
2. Use `num *= 2` instead of `num=num*2`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of little steps in this word problem;  It might help to draw a picture:

Starting with one 'grain' on the first square

```
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|  1 |    |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|    |    |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |
```

and doubling each square:

```
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|  1 |  2 |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|    |    |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |
```

so far so good.  we are interested in how much grain total, though, so the king has had to pay

```
1 + 2 = 3
```

the cost of *all* squares, not just the last.  Continuing:

```
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|  1 |  2 |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |  
|  4 |  8 |  
+----+----+--
|    |    |  

1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15 grains
```

and so on, we'll end up with

```
1 + 2 + ( 64 times ) grains
```

whatever number that turns out to be.

There's one last part to the problem, though; you are to express your answer not in "grains" but in "pounds", so 
do be sure to convert the result to the correct units